# How to add array values in drop down list using java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Friends please tell how to add list of array values in drop down list using java servlet.

Please check the below code and tell any error in this code..

My Jsp Page.... DropDown.jsp

```
<body onload="callAction()">
<form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callAction() {
        document.location.href="http://localhost:8084/Servlet/DropDown";
    }
</script>

<select name="Day"><option>Day</option>
    <c:forEach items="${Data}" var="d">
        <option value="${d}">${d}</option>
    </c:forEach>      
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

My Servlet page DropDown.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
int[] day=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};

    request.setAttribute("Data", day);

 response.sendRedirect("DropDown.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT***

*servlet*

```
int[] day=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
request.setAttribute("Data", day);//<-- no loop required !
//response.sendRedirect("DropDown.jsp");//<-- this will make a new request
request.getRequestDispatcher("DropDown.jsp").forward(request, response);//<-- forward it
```

*DropDown.jsp:*

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<select name="Day">
    <option>Day</option>
    <c:forEach var="d" items="${Data}">
      <option value="${d}">${d}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: @Aravind I am not getting the values.. Plz check the code, now I updated the full code.. Please check and reply for that..

Comment: @Aravind.. Currently nothing displaying on the browser.. Please check the javascript and tell any error on this..

Comment: @ShajiSS, remove that script tag from jsp, not needed, tell me do you have only this servlet and jsp in your web-app? here your servlet needs to be invoked before jsp

Comment: @ShajiSS, jsp cannot render values from the request attributes after page load, still if you need in that way you will need ajax

Comment: @ShajiSS, kindly accept the answer, as it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<=day.length;i++)
    {
        request.setAttribute("data", day[i]);
    }
```

it will override the `data` attribute and replace a new value. just set attribute with the array.

request.setAttribute("data",day);

then in your `select` use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/download.html) and import the jstl tag library

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<select name="Day">
   <c:foreach items="${data}" var="d">
    <option>${d}</option>
    </c:foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: it will not take effect because you are using response.redirect. you must use requestdispatcher